# Upgrade of php not working on Late 2011 High Sierra

Tags: homebrew, php

I have a late 2011 Macbook pro and want to setup my development environment.However, am struggling with php version. It is currently set to the default 7.1.16.

I was hoping to do it with brew, but I noticed that the version of brew I installed is for the latest versions of mac. So none of my brew commands are working.

How do update my php version without brew?

I tried with curl but when I check the version is still set to the default one.

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3
```

Or would there be a way to install a brew version that is compatible to High Sierra?

Comment: Use macports rather than homebrew. It provides a version for each os version from Tiger to the latest and or all types of cpu

Comment: @mmmmmm I installed macports and ran sudo port install php73. It installed php73 as it seemed, but I still see php 7.1 after restarting the terminal.

Comment: What is your $PATH ? what does `which php` print? Basically you need /opt/local/bin before /usr/bin

Comment: @mmmmmm which php prints /usr/bin/php

Comment: What is your $PATH ?